# Regular Expression to match additional optional word

Tags: javascript, regex

I have directory strings like so:

```
var list = ['/styles/portal/dragonfruit/green.scss',
'/styles/portal/version5/blue.scss',
'/styles/portal/version5/custom/company.scss',
'/styles/portal/version5/custom/industry.scss',
'/styles/portal/version5/custom/corporation.scss',
'/styles/portal/version5/admin/green.scss',
'/styles/portal/version5/admin/blue.scss'];
```

And I'd like to remove the starting styles/portal/version5/ portion from all strings, and optionally remove custom as well if it exists.

The output after processing this list would read:

```
/green.scss
/blue.scss
/company.scss
/industry.scss
/corporation.scss
/admin/green.scss
/admin/blue.scss
```

How do I optionally target the word match of custom when using a string.replace method?

So far I have:

```
var result = item.replace('styles/portal/version5/', '')
```

Comment: How come the first string only left with `/green.css` ? shouldn't it be left intact ?

Comment: `lastIndexOf` can be your friend.

Comment: @CodeManiac That was a typo on my part, obfuscating internal naming scheme failure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `non captured group` and make it optional

[image]

```js
var list = ['/styles/portal/dragonfruit/green.scss','/styles/portal/version5/blue.scss','/styles/portal/version5/custom/company.scss','/styles/portal/version5/custom/industry.scss','/styles/portal/version5/custom/corporation.scss','/styles/portal/version5/admin/green.scss','/styles/portal/version5/admin/blue.scss'];

let final = list.map(v => v.replace(/^\/?styles\/portal\/version5(?:\/custom)?/, ''))

console.log(final)
```

Comment: Thank you. The graphic above is above and beyond in helping visualize the matching.